Error when inserting formulas of different language via AppScript
When I enter a formula manually, it works perfectly, but when the same formula is entered via script, it displays #Error! or #Name.
I would like to know if anyone has ever encountered this problem and could help me.
Below is the code:
 targetSheet.getRange('U2:V').clearContent();
 
  rangeU2.setFormula('=ARRAYFORMULA(SEERRO(SE(M2:M = ""; ""; PROCV(M2:M; Players!C2:E; 3; FALSO));""))');
  rangeV2.setFormula('=ARRAYFORMULA(SE(S2:S = ""; ""; SE(U2:U = ""; ""; SE(S2:S=U2:U; G2:G; SE(G2:G="victory"; "defeat"; "victory")))))');
}`

Here is an image describing where I am using the script:
I have tested simple formulas such as a sum and more elaborate formulas, and both have the same behavior.

I have already granted all the permissions that the Script requests.

There are no errors when executing the Script

The cell is filled perfectly with the formula but displays an error.



What's the error message? Can you share a live sheet? (You can use this tool to create an anonymous example sheet.) I have encountered similar error before but haven't noticed a pattern. So can't really help without the exact sheet. Maybe others can

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Let's wait for the OP to comment, but I'm not sure the edited title corresponds to their situation (I don't believe they want to translate anything).

@user27425627 I don't believe that either.  The issue is different language formulas  throws error in sheet. Translating fixes the issue.

Ok so, to see if I understand the problem: what is displayed by Google Sheets as a cell's formula, isn't really what the cell contains? I.e., when a formula is typed in a language other than English, the API translates the formula internally, but still displays the formula in the user's language? And moreover, this internal-translation mechanism doesn't work when a script inserts the formula, which is thus not understood by Google Sheets?

@user27425627 Hmm... I'm not sure about the internals of how this operates. Btw, If you are curious and want to know Tanaike's solution worked, this should be easy to test....just change the spreadsheet language to portuguese and  reproduce the problem by OP and test the solution below.

Actually, @TheMaster, no: the display language reflects the user's Google account settings. Changing the spreadsheet's locale to, say, Spanish means that formulae can be typed in that language, but when entered they are still translated to and displayed in the user's Google account's language. So to reflect the exact same situation as the OP (it might not affect the end result, but it might do), that setting has to be changed too (and it takes time to take effect and I'm lazy enough to not do it).

When I tested your showing script, I also confirmed the same issue. From your showing formula, for example, SEERRO and SE might be IFERROR and IF in Portuguese, respectively? If my understanding is correct, I'm worried that this might be the reason for this issue. So, in order to avoid this issue, how about the following patterns?
Pattern 1:
In this pattern, the language is manually changed, and the modified formulas are used.
From:
=ARRAYFORMULA(SEERRO(SE(M2:M = ""; ""; PROCV(M2:M; Players!C2:E; 3; FALSO));""))

=ARRAYFORMULA(SE(S2:S = ""; ""; SE(U2:U = ""; ""; SE(S2:S=U2:U; G2:G; SE(G2:G="victory"; "defeat"; "victory")))))

To:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(M2:M = "", "", VLOOKUP(M2:M, Players!C2:E, 3, FALSE)),""))

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(S2:S = "", "", IF(U2:U = "", "", IF(S2:S=U2:U, G2:G, IF(G2:G="victory", "defeat", "victory")))))

Pattern 2:
The translation of language is changed by a script.
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const range1 = sheet.getRange("U2");
const range2 = sheet.getRange("V2");

const formula1 = `=ARRAYFORMULA(SEERRO(SE(M2:M = ""; ""; PROCV(M2:M; Players!C2:E; 3; FALSO));""))`;
const formula2 = `=ARRAYFORMULA(SE(S2:S = ""; ""; SE(U2:U = ""; ""; SE(S2:S=U2:U; G2:G; SE(G2:G="victory"; "defeat"; "victory")))))`;
range1.setFormula(LanguageApp.translate(formula1, "pt", "en"));
range2.setFormula(LanguageApp.translate(formula2, "pt", "en"));

In this script, formula1 and formula2 are put into cells "U2" and "V2" of the active sheet. This is a simple sample script. So, please modify the sheet and the cell range to your actual situation.
Pattern 3:
Use Sheets API. When Sheets API is used, the language is automatically converted when the following script is used, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services.
const ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
const range1 = "'Sheet1'!U2";
const range2 = "'Sheet1'!V2";
const formula1 = `=ARRAYFORMULA(SEERRO(SE(M2:M = ""; ""; PROCV(M2:M; Players!C2:E; 3; FALSO));""))`;
const formula2 = `=ARRAYFORMULA(SE(S2:S = ""; ""; SE(U2:U = ""; ""; SE(S2:S=U2:U; G2:G; SE(G2:G="victory"; "defeat"; "victory")))))`;
const data = [
  { values: [[formula1]], range: range1 },
  { values: [[formula2]], range: range2 }
];
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, ssId);

In this script, formula1 and formula2 are put into cells 'Sheet1'!U2 and 'Sheet1'!V2, respectively. When the formulas are put, the formulas are converted like "Pattern 1". This is a simple sample script. So, please modify the ranges to your actual situation.
References:

translate(text, sourceLanguage, targetLanguage)
Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate


So, @David, has this solved the issue? I'm very curious.
