NAME error hiperlink function Apps Script Google Sheets
i am getting a strange error, #NAME? error while inserting formula into cell.
Heres the code:
var email = empresa[0][4];
var linkEmail = "mailto:"+email;
view.getRange("F6").setFormula('=hiperlink("'+linkEmail+'")'); // Email

i have tried with different approaches, but the same results, dont know if its a String error or something else, but i just copy and paste the content of cell into another cell and it work.
error:

same content, working:

i just want to create a mailto hyperlink with a existing list of clients.


Hi. In English, the formula is hyperlink and not hiperlink.

@Tedinoz In OP's language, hiperlink should work as shown in his second screenshot.

Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79033170/error-when-inserting-formulas-of-different-language-via-appscript

@TheMaster Thanks. I was  going to ask about “locale” but then thought “the script editor is in English so it would require ‘the English version of the function (‘hyperlink’)”. Anyway, now removing my foot from my mouth .

There is a typo in your formula. It should be hyperlink instead of hiperlink.

That's not the issue. OP says: but i just copy and paste the content of cell into another cell and it work. if the typo was  the issue, it wouldn't work even if you copy and paste.

it worked, thank you

Ouch, I guess I missed that part.
